# When creating ISO-8859-1 XML with node.js iconv-lite and iconv modules fail

Tags: node.js, express, utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv

Im trying to create XML file in ISO-8859-1 charset, but I am unable to encode UTF-8 text string to ISO-8859-1.

```
var xmlStr = '<!-- This line needs to be here to test äöå -->';
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
var xmlStr = iconv.convert(xmlStr);
```

Same thing happens when using iconv-lite

```
var xmlStr = '<!-- This line needs to be here to test äöå -->';
var iconv  = require('iconv-lite');
xmlStr = iconv.encode(new Buffer(xmlStr), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Yet encoding works fine if I add extra character outside the tags (with both modules). In this case even the characters inside the tag are encoded correctly.

```
var xmlStr = 'ö<!-- This line needs to be here to test äöå -->';
var iconv  = require('iconv-lite');
xmlStr = iconv.encode(new Buffer(xmlStr), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Im using this to create dynamic XML files to be downloaded through express

```
res.set("content-type", "application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1");
res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.xml");
res.set('transfer-encoding', 'binary');
res.send(xmlStr);
```

I'm guessing that letter in beginning tells "somebody" from where to make the encoding, but it is not smart enough to understand letters from inside the xml tags as most of the string is ok with both charsets.

Comment: The first example works fine in my Windows nodejs v11.7.0 console with iconv@2.3.2.

Comment: Besides, if you want to encode an XML document, you would tell the XML writer which encoding you want and it would 1) convert the encoding of the text, 2) replace unsupported characters with character entity references, and 3) write the encoding into the XML declaration.

Comment: Thanks Tom for comments. I updated my node and modules - no change (v10.15.1 and iconv@2.3.2). Running on mac Os. I'm using xmlbuilder  to create the XML, then encoding it to ISO-8859-1 and sending it through express to customer as attachment /file upload. E.g. the actual file is written the first time on client machine. And it all works if there is this special character in the beginning of the XML variable. (var mlStr = 'ä' + xmlStr;)